# Dealing with models and model methods using Node + Knex + Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I was hoping to get some help. I just started using Postgres with my Node applications and am curious to find out how to go about dealing with models and model methods. What is the best practice when working with Node and Postgres in regards to models and methods? I was looking around and all I could find is something called Objection, but is it absolutely necessary I take that route?

Ideally I would like to have a model.js file for each component but I have not seen them used when dealing with Postgres + Node.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks guys, hope you all had a great Thanksgiving!

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that viewer can understand basic javascript modules and that the codes are mostly self explanatory

### This is my model.js file

```js
module.exports = ({
 knex = require('./connection'),
 name = '',
 tableName = '',
 selectableProps = [],
 timeout = 1000
}) => {
    const query = knex.from(tableName)

    const create = props => {
      delete props.id
      return knex.insert(props)
        .returning(selectableProps)
        .into(tableName)
        .timeout(timeout)
    }
    const findAll = () => {
      return knex.select(selectableProps)
        .from(tableName)
        .timeout(timeout)
    }
    const find = filters => {
      return knex.select(selectableProps)
        .from(tableName)
        .where(filters)
        .timeout(timeout)
    }
    
    const update = (id, props) => {
      delete props.id
  
      return knex.update(props)
        .from(tableName)
        .where({
          id
        })
        .returning(selectableProps)
        .timeout(timeout)
    }
  
    const destroy = id => {
      return knex.del()
        .from(tableName)
        .where({
          id
        })
        .timeout(timeout)
    }
  
    return {
      query,
      name,
      tableName,
      selectableProps,
      timeout,
      create,
      findAll,
      find,
      update,
      destroy
    }
  }
```

### This is my controller.js file

```js
const model = require('./model');

const user = model({
 name: "users",
 tableName: "tbl_users",
});

const getAllUsers = async (req, res, next)=>{
 let result = await user.findAll();
 res.send(result);
}

module.exports = { getAllUsers }
```

### And Lastly a the connection.js file

```js
const knex = require('knex')({
client: 'pg',
connection: {
  host: 'YOUR_HOST_ADDR',
  user: 'YOUR_USERNAME',
  password: 'YOUR_PASS',
  database: 'YOUR_DB_NAME'
},
pool: {
  min: 0,
  max: 7
}
});

module.exports = knex;
```